# Unable to change label text when Invoking Method through Reflection in c#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

First Look at my code

```
namespace HealthClub
{
    public partial class frmTrainerMaster : Form
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        frmHome Home = new frmHome();
        public frmTrainerMaster()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }
    }

    private void frmTrainerMaster_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            FillValues("UserNameText");            
        }


   public void FillValues(string UserName)
    {
        DataTable DT;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        try
        {
            cmd.Connection = Connections.Connection[UserName];
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "TrainerMaster_pro";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Option", "FillValues".Trim());
            if (Connections.Connection[UserName].State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                Connections.Connection[UserName].Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DT = new DataTable();
            adp.Fill(DT);
            lblId___.Text = DT.Rows[0][0].ToString();                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Dispose();
            Connections.Connection[UserName].Close();                
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am calling FillValues() from another class like this

```
class AnotherClass
{
public void TestMethod(string FormName)
{
    Type tp = Type.GetType("HealthClub." + FormName);
                object myobj = Activator.CreateInstance(tp);
                MethodInfo method = myobj.GetType().GetMethod("FillValues");
                object[] parametersArray = new object[] { UserName };
                method.Invoke(myobj, parametersArray);    
}
}
```

If you look at the FillValues(), I am assigning the database value to a label. When I am calling it in my first class in page load it's working fine.

But when I am Invoking the medthod from second class, Method invokes but database value does not assign to the label.

What extra effort I need to do ?

Comment: Well you're creating a new instance of the form - but never actually displaying it. My guess is that you should be using an *existing* instance of the form instead...

Comment: Can you please brief ?

Comment: Um, I've explained everything I can - I don't know what more I can say. There's not much point creating a form if you're never showing it, and that's what you're doing at the moment.

Comment: U mean I'll have to pass the existing instance of first class at the time of invoking the method ?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise how do you expect anything to know which form you're trying to populate?

Comment: Yes - Also reflection seems a bit of overkill - cleaner way is to use interface defining the settor.

Comment: But how will I invoke the method without creating object ?  Sorry I don't have much experience.

Comment: You need to pass reference to frmTrainerMaster instance to the class from where you want to call FillValues() and invoke it like frmTrainerMaster reference; reference.FillValues();

Comment: Hi @OndrejSvejdar. Can you please Explain in my code ?   It will be a great help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to assign some value to a control through Method Call from another class in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41136940/how-to-assign-some-value-to-a-control-through-method-call-from-another-class-in)

Answer (score 0):

There is a class and there is an instance. This is very basic concept you need to understand (not just in C#, but in any objective-oriented language).

```
// class example
class FrmTrainerMaster  { public int SomeProperty { get; set;} }
```

When you create new instance:

```
// creates one window
var frmTrainerMasterInstanceOne = new FrmTrainerMaster();
frmTrainerMasterInstanceOne.SomeProperty = 1; 

// creates second window
var frmTrainerMasterInstanceTwo = new FrmTrainerMaster();
frmTrainerMasterInstanceTwo.SomeProperty = 2;
```

Instances are SEPARATE - so at this point querying

```
// will return 1 
Console.Out.WriteLine(frmTrainerMasterInstanceOne.SomeProperty);
// will return 2 
Console.Out.WriteLine(frmTrainerMasterInstanceTwo.SomeProperty);
```

With reflection `var myobj = Type.GetType("HealthClub.FrmTrainerMaster");` is equal to `var myobj = new FrmTrainerMaster();` so by doing anything with `myobj`, you still can't affect `frmTrainerMasterInstanceOne` or `frmTrainerMasterInstanceTwo`.

What do you need is actually method how to pass reference to instance (of `FrmTrainerMaster` class) to place where you need it (lets call it `AnotherForm`), there is no magic list of all instances for given class unless you explicitly build it.

```
public partial class FrmTrainerMaster : Form
{
  public void FillValues(string userName) { ... }
}
```

One way is via constructor injection (generally proffered - since at time when object (`AnotherForm`) is constructed you have it in valid state (i.e. with all dependencies initialized).

```
public class AnotherForm : Form {
   private readonly FrmTrainMaster _frmTrainMaster;
   public AnotherForm(FrmTrainMaster frmTrainMaster) {
     if (frmTrainMaster == null) {
       throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(frmTrainMaster));
     }
     _frmTrainMaster = frmTrainMaster;
   }
}
```

Or via setter injection:

```
public class AnotherForm : Form {
  private FrmTrainMaster _frmTrainMaster;
  public FrmTrainMaster MasterForm { set { _frmTrainMaster = value; } }
}
```

Either way the reflection is not necessary at all. At any place in your `AnotherForm` you can just call

```
class AnotherForm : Form {
  ...
  public void FooMethodThatCallFillValues() {
    _frmTrainMaster.FillValues("...");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Ondrej for your answer. Actually I am calling `FillValues()` by sending class name to `AnotherClass`. So how can I invoke it without reflection ?   I edited my question

Comment: @ShaiwalTripathi - you can't send just class name - you need to send reference to the class instance. See my update.

Comment: I am dynamically sending form name to `AnotherForm` such as `frmTrainerMaster` from a `ThirdClass`. So as you said that I will have to send reference of instance to `AnotherClass`. But how will I get reference in `ThirdClass`  so I can pass it to `AnotherForm` ?  Can you please provide me a example ?    I am fade up..

Comment: @ShaiwalTripathi - I recommend to reformulate your question & share not just code but what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi @Ondrej I asked a new question which will clear you everything. Please can you look at that ?    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41136940/how-to-assign-some-value-to-a-control-through-method-call-from-another-class-in