# How to assign some value to a control through Method Call from another class in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, pass-by-reference

I am trying to make a global `Reset` class which reset all the values in a form and called the initial Method of that form. I pass the Form Name dynamically to `Reset` class and reset all the control's value and called the Method of that form. Here is my Code...
Reset Class

```
class Reset
{
    public void BlankAll(string FormName, Panel pnl, string UserName)
    {          
        foreach (Control ch in pnl.Controls)     // this foreach loop reset the values of each control, it's working fine. So don't bother about it.
        {
            if (ch.Name.Substring(ch.Name.Length - 3) != "_NI")
            {
                if (ch is TextBox || ch is ComboBox)
                    ch.Text = string.Empty;
                else if (ch is DateTimePicker)
                    ch.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
                else if (ch is DataGridView)
                {                        
                    DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)pnl.Controls.Find(ch.Name, true).SingleOrDefault();
                    for (int i = dgv.Rows.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
                    {
                        dgv.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
                    }
                    for (int i = 1; i < dgv.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        dgv.Rows[0].Cells[i].Value = string.Empty;
                    }

                }
            }
        }            

        Type tp = Type.GetType("HealthClub." + FormName);     // HealthClub is NameSpace
        object myobj = Activator.CreateInstance(tp);
        MethodInfo method = myobj.GetType().GetMethod("FillValues");   // FillValues is the method which I am trying to call
        object[] parametersArray = new object[] { UserName };
        method.Invoke(myobj, parametersArray);    

    }
}
```

Here is `FillValues` Method in `Form1` which I want to Invoke from `Reset` class

```
public void FillValues(string UserName)
{
    DataTable DT;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    try
    {
        cmd.Connection = Connections.Connection[UserName];
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "TrainerMaster_pro";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Option", "FillValues".Trim());
        if (Connections.Connection[UserName].State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            Connections.Connection[UserName].Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DT = new DataTable();
        adp.Fill(DT);                
        lblId___.Text = DT.Rows[0][0].ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.Dispose();
        Connections.Connection[UserName].Close();                
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to Reset `Form1` from `Form2` through `Reset` class. So I am doing this in `Form2`

```
private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Reset RS = new Reset();
    RS.BlankAll("Form1", pnl, UserName);
}
```

Everything is working fine and Method `FillValues` invoke successfully but the main problem is database value is not assigning to lblId___ in `FillValues` Method. I understand this because in my `Reset` class I am creating the new object for the form which I am passing. Some people suggest me to Invoke method using **call by reference**.

How can do that?

Please help guys....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At BlankAll, you pass the name of the form, the the form itself. 
so your signature should look like this

```
class Reset
{
    public void BlankAll(Form form, Panel pnl, string UserName)
    {          
        foreach (Control ch in pnl.Controls) 
        {
            if (ch.Name.Substring(ch.Name.Length - 3) != "_NI")
            {
                if (ch is TextBox || ch is ComboBox)
                    ch.Text = string.Empty;
                else if (ch is DateTimePicker)
                    ch.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
                else if (ch is DataGridView)
                {                        
                    DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)pnl.Controls.Find(ch.Name, true).SingleOrDefault();
                    for (int i = dgv.Rows.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
                    {
                        dgv.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
                    }
                    for (int i = 1; i < dgv.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        dgv.Rows[0].Cells[i].Value = string.Empty;
                    }
                }
            }

     Type tp = Type.GetType("HealthClub." + form.Name);
     object myobj = Activator.CreateInstance(tp);
     MethodInfo method = myobj.GetType().GetMethod("FillValues");   
     object[] parametersArray = new object[] {form, UserName };
     form.Refresh();
        }
```

When Calling the fill you should pass the form so the method will know "which" label it should update

```
public void FillValues(Form form, string UserName)
{
   DataTable DT;
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
   try
   {
       cmd.Connection = Connections.Connection[UserName];
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       cmd.CommandText = "TrainerMaster_pro";
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Option", "FillValues".Trim());
       if (Connections.Connection[UserName].State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            Connections.Connection[UserName].Open();
       SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
       DT = new DataTable();
       adp.Fill(DT);                
       form.lblId___.Text = DT.Rows[0][0].ToString();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
     }
     finally
     {
       cmd.Parameters.Clear();
       cmd.Dispose();
       Connections.Connection[UserName].Close();                
     }
}
```

Comment: @ShaiwalTripathi
BlankAll Method is in your form?
then you call should look like this
BlankAll(this, panel1, "admin");

Comment: `FillValues` method doesn't return any value so what is the use of SomeDatacontainer ?

Comment: @ShaiwalTripathi pass the form as argument.

Answer (score 0):

Shaiwal you can achieve this by two ways.

1) Pass the form as a reference rather passing the form name and invoke the intial method.

2) You can use delegate to pass method reference and invoke method after performing your work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you are creating the instance of the reset class you can pass the reference of the form using this keyword as a parameter in the constructor so that you don't require to create new instance of the form.

You can do something like below

```
Reset RS = new Reset(this);
```

Make a parameter constructor in the Reset Class that accepts this like below

```
Public Reset(Form currentForm)
{
    //set the form variable or property here as per your requirement
}
```

Comment: Hi @Nikunj `FillValues` is in `Form1` and I am calling `BlankAll` method from `Form2` then why I will pass the reference of `Form2` ?

Comment: @ShaiwalTripathi Yes!